# Is there a way we can make pull run yml file from different directory then the root repository directory?

Tags: ansible, ansible-pull

Repo structure:

- xyz

  - lmn

    - a.yml
    - roles

      - test

        - tasks
        - vars
          ...

I want ansible pull to download xyz repo but run a.yml file after download.
Is this something possible?

Run output:

[root@GHOST]# ansible-pull -U https://xyz.git -i 127.0.0.1 -d . lmn/a.yml

Starting Ansible Pull at 2021-07-05 09:13:48

/bin/ansible-pull -U https://xyz.git -i 127.0.0.1 -d . lmn/a.yml

[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: GHOST

Username for 'https://github.com': xxxxxx

Password for 'https://xxxxxx@github.com':

localhost | FAILED! => {
"changed": false,
"msg": "Failed to init/update submodules: Submodule 'qwerty/truth/best' (https://github.com/hello.git) registered for path 'qwerty/truth/best'\nNo submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'busy/cookbooks/cook'\n"
}

Comment: `ansible-pull` lets you specify a playbook as a positional argument. Have you tried that?

Comment: tried this but it didn't work.   ansible-pull -U https://xyz -i 127.0.0.1 xyz/lmn/a.yml.

Comment: Hi Manish Kumar Singh welcome to SO. Please ban the use of the phrase "it didn't work" from your vocabulary while asking for help. Had you [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68249686/edit) and included the actual command you used and the actual error it produced, you may receive help unsticking that problem. As it stands now, only you and your computer know what is actually happening, which doesn't help the Internet to help you help yourself. Read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page,
and the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) part

Comment: Thanks for the guiding comment Daniel. Updated main question with more outputs for perusal.

Comment: Independent of the very clear error message about the submodules being incorrect, the fine manual says [`-d` must be an absolute path](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/cli/ansible-pull.html#cmdoption-ansible-pull-d), so `-d .` will not get it done, although `-d $PWD` should do what you intended. Are you able to `git clone --recursive` that repo outside of ansible-pull?

Comment: Yes `git clone --recursive` works fine. The thing is I have other directories under `xyz` repro which contains submodules. I am not interested in invoking those submodules but instead wants to run the yml file deep inside directory structure `xyz/lmn/a.yml`. As per ansible-pull documentation what I understand is repo root directoy should have local.yml or some other yml file whose name can be passed as positional argument.